# How do I replace the "node view" screen in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have no need for the node "view" screen/tab for certain types of content.
Instead, when a user goes into /node/nid I wish to show the node edit form.

Any ideas on how I do that?

thanks,
Omer.

Comment: I am not sure it's a good idea. First, not all users can edit a form, but possibly all users can see a node (if anonymous users cannot see nodes, then it doesn't make sense to create a site, if not in the case the site is thought to be seen from a restricted number of users); second, there could be a numbers of other tabs, together with the tab View, that would be anymore accessible.

Comment: thanks, but in the site I am working on it does makes sense, in certain cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it, would be to use `hook_menu_alter` to change the `node/[nid]` menu item and call you own function. In that function you could check the node type and either call the function used to display the node or the one used to display the node form.

Comment: I tried that. I use pathauto to change the prefix from 'node' to something else (e.g. 'pref'), and implemented hook_menu_alter to call a function that renders the edit form at the same path. 
The pathauto setting seems to override my menu_alter, as I still see the view form (changing my menu_alter to 'other_pref' renders the form with no problem)

Comment: Pathauto doesn't change the internal path, so even if you change node/[nid] to pref/[nid], it is still node/[nid] that's called internally. You don't need to change the url with the `hook_menu_alter`, only the menu callback.

Comment: my bad. mixed up hook_menu and hook_menu_alter. I'm looking into hook_menu_alter, seems to be in the right direction.